# No N+1 query without preloading associations in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm experiencing a strange behavior in Rails, where I expected N+1 query but did not get it :)

Models

```
Post
has_one :moderated_record


ModeratedRecord
belongs_to :record, polymorphic: true
belongs_to :moderation_flow 

ModerationFlow
has_many :moderation_steps

ModerationLog
belongs_to :moderated_record
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :moderation_step

ModerationStep
belongs_to :moderation_flow
has_many :moderation_logs
```

Now the following code

```
posts.filter_map do |post|
   post.moderated_record.moderation_flow.moderation_steps.find do |step|
     step.moderation_logs.all?(:&not_moderated_yet?)
   end
end
```

does not execute n+1, instead it gets all entities with condition like id in ()

For instance:

```
SELECT * from moderation_steps where moderation_flow_id IN (...)

SELECT * from moderation_logs where moderation_step_id IN (...)
```

I created a spec with these queries and I see there is no n+1

I understand that `has_one` won't generate n+1, but I would expect for `post.moderated_record.moderation_flow.moderation_steps` to execute new query in each iteration (for each post)

Any opinions on this?

Worth mentioning that I'm using ActiveRecord and Postgres database

Comment: Have you tried `.to_sql` to see what query it generates?

Comment: @dbugger The version of Rails is 7.0.8
I think the question is quite detailed and clear

Comment: @Beartech yes, tried it, also created a spec as mentioned, but no n+1 query

Comment: @aldm Could you show how the `posts` variable is set, please? I suppose, it probably has `.includes`. That is why N + 1 is not happening.